# facebook like button displaying incorrectly (debug shows empty href)

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm having an issue with the facebook like button on website:
according to the facebook lint tool my like buttons are:
`<div class="fb-like" data-href="" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false"></div>`

however my page has:
`<div class="fb-like" data-href="<?=$value['actions'][1]['link'];>" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false"></div></p><hr />`
and I'm 100% sure that `$value['actions'][1]['link']` actually contains a valid facebook URL
(when looked at my page without re-rendering, it also shows this URL)

-

With this output you'd expect the like not to function, however it does:

if I like a status message, it tells on the page that I liked it, and it is the first like for that item;

however if I go to facebook, it states that I liked it, and also states that there are x other likes.

If I refresh the page, it's again like I didn't like the item yet; altough it's the same item

-

I hope you understood my problem, isn't that easy to explain...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, remove the loading of the Facebook scripts and check your view source to ensure the data-href is populating correctly prior to the Facebook parser getting to it.

Comment: it is, even after facebook parsed it; when I view it in my browser
however facebook lint shows it as empty
link: http://www.daydreamer.eu/#p/blog (I'm correctly re-parsing AFTER AJAX-load, so that's not the issue)

Comment: The data-href attribute is NOT being set in the html5 tag.  Facebook defaults to the og:url meta tag or the page location.  In this case it's using `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.daydreamer.eu%2F%23p%2Fblog` from the `<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.daydreamer.eu"/>` tag.  Either set the og:url correctly or set the HTML5 tag correctly.

Comment: found the problem, has to do with graph: I was somehow still connected/logged in to my test setup; therefor it worked on my browser (in the status array there was an action->0/1(comment/like)->link)

now the issue became: how do I get a like-box from the graph-ID?
(trying things out atm)

Comment: can be seen withthe api explorer: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=123123111100709_213131188766567

problem is that this method requires authenticated users (basic access token)